# a functions default parameters remain after the function was executed, what do?

Tags: javascript

after setting default parameters in a function and then calling the function again without those parameters makes them still remain and I want them to be "cleared" on every function call.

this feels super simple but I don't get it... I'm somewhat of a beginner

```js
function test(){
 console.log(name)
 let test = (name !== "undefined") ? "test" : "welp"
}

test(name="harry")
test()
```

why does second test() still output "harry"?
can it be fixed without giving up on default parameters?

I hoped "use strict" would help but no.

Comment: The `name="harry"` in your first `test()` creates a global variable called `name` with `"harry"` in it. That global variable is set for both calls to `test()`.

Comment: `"use strict"` would've helped you realize that you're creating a new variable if you used something other than `name` ([`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a global property on the `window` object, so it doesn't throw an error when you do `name=...` without first declaring it), if you were to use something else like `test(foo="harry")` you would get an error.

Comment: hm the goal in the actual code was to allow me to rewrite defaults provided by a config.
example:

let configs = {
"test":{
"name":"johndoe"
}
}
test(name=harry, configs.test)

the idea was to let default parameters override the config.

so no way to make it non global as default parameter ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the line:

```
test(name="harry")
```

You didn't set a default parameter, you defined a global variable which persists in the global scope and pollutes said scope with that value (this is why globals are bad).

To use default parameters, you write the code a little differently is all:

```js
// defining the function, and setting its default parameter
// named "name", and the value to "Harry":
function test(name = "Harry"){
 console.log(name)
 let test = (name !== "undefined") ? "test" : "welp"
}

test("Marge") // logs Marge
test() // logs Harry
```

Alternatively you could have written the same a little differently:

```js
// defining the function, and setting its default parameter
// named "name", and the value to "Harry":
const test = function (name = "Harry"){
 console.log(name)
 let test = (name !== "undefined") ? "test" : "welp"
}

test("Marge") // logs Marge
test() // logs Harry
```

And again, but using an Arrow function:

```js
// defining the function, and setting its default parameter
// named "name", and the value to "Harry":
const test = (name = "Harry") => {
 console.log(name)
 let test = (name !== "undefined") ? "test" : "welp"
}

test("Marge") // logs Marge
test() // logs Harry
```

Or, in the event you want multiple defaults:

```js
// defining the function, and a parameter to be passed
// to the function, named "opts":
const test = function(opts) {
  // defining the defaults for the function
  // (there are also alternatives to this
  // approach, but this is my example:
  let defaults = {
      givenName: "Harry",
      familyName: "Harrison"
    },
    // here we "merge" the defaults with the
    // user-supplied options:
    details = Object.assign(defaults, opts),
    // define the name using a template-literal,
    // which interpolates the JavaScript into the
    // String:
    name = `${details.givenName} ${details.familyName}`;
  console.log(name)
  let test = (name !== "undefined") ? "test" : "welp"
}

test({
  givenName: "Marge"
}) // logs Marge Harrison
test({
  familyName: "Kanagarathnam"
}); // logs Harry Kanagarathnam
test() // logs Harry Harrison
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: hmm too bad I can't prefix it with var or something to only make it work in that function.

i mean this works too assuming that I can add key:value pairs from a json as the function's default parameters. (google not giving me suggestions so I might be doing stomething bad...)

Comment: I'm not sure I appreciate the problem you're trying to solve, but it sounds like the problem you're stuck on is - probably - a different question than the one you asked here. It may be worth reading the "*[ask]*" guidance, and asking a new question once you've clarified the exact problem; adding a link to this question might help add context for that new question though. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful with the information I've got so far.

Comment: cool, thanks!!! I believe the Object.assign might do what I need